Conditions on a lattice to allow partitioning sets of elements into disjoint generators
Given a distributive lattice L and a finite set of elements S, I'd like to produce a finite set of elements T such that

$t_i \land t_j = \bot_L$

$t_i = \bigwedge U_i$ for some $U_i \subseteq S$

$s_k = \bigvee W_k$ for some $W_k \subseteq T$


I'm curious what conditions I might impose on L to ensure this is possible. Being a Boolean algebra certainly suffices.
Here's an intuitive picture:


I'm curious what conditions I might impose on
$L$ to ensure this is possible.

First note: the existence of $T$ depends on both $L$ and $S$.
Second note: I'm going to explain only the case
where $S$ contains at least two nonzero elements of $L$.
I will state the answer
in the remaining easy cases later, but I will
omit the explanation.

Statement. Given a distributive lattice $L$ with zero element $\bot_L$ and a finite
subset $S\subseteq L$ containing at least two nonzero elements,
there exists a subset $T\subseteq L$
satisfying 1., 2., 3. if and only if the sublattice $\langle S\rangle$
of $L$ that is generated by $S$ is a finite Boolean sublattice of $L$
that contains the element $\bot_L$ of $L$.
Moreover, the set $T$ is almost uniquely determined:
$T$ is either the set of atoms of the finite Boolean lattice
$\langle S\rangle$ or it is the union of the set $\{\bot_L\}$
with the set of atoms of the finite Boolean lattice
$\langle S\rangle$. 
Reasoning.
Assume that there is a $T$ satisfying 1., 2., 3.
Item 2. states that every element of $T$
is a meet of elements of $S$, so
$\langle T\rangle \subseteq \langle S\rangle$.
(I'm comparing the sublattices generated by $T$ and $S$.)
Similarly, Item 3. guarantees that
$\langle S\rangle \subseteq \langle T\rangle$.
Since $S$ is finite and $L$ is distributive,
$\langle S\rangle$ is finite,
hence $\langle T\rangle=\langle S\rangle$ is finite.
We must have $|T|>1$, since if $|T|\leq 1$
we would have $|S-\{\bot_L\}|\leq 1$ (using Item 3.),
and this contradicts the assumption that
$S$ contains at least two nonzero elements.
By the above and Item 1., $|T|>1$ and
the finite sublattice $\langle T\rangle$ is generated
by the set $T$ of pairwise disjoint elements.
This forces $\langle T\rangle$ to be finite, Boolean,
to contain $\bot_L$, and for $T$ to be either the set
of atoms of $\langle T\rangle$ or the set
of atoms union $\{\bot_L\}$.
This completes the argument that
$\langle S\rangle = \langle T\rangle$
is finite, Boolean,
contains $\bot_L$, and for $T$ to be either the set
of atoms of $\langle S\rangle$ or the set
of atoms union $\{\bot_L\}$.
Conversely, assume that
$\langle S\rangle$
is finite, Boolean, and
contains $\bot_L$. We still assume that $S$
contains at least two nonzero elements of $L$,
so $\langle S\rangle$ has at least two atoms.
Let $T$ be the set of atoms of $\langle S\rangle$ or the set
of atoms union $\{\bot_L\}$. With these choices
Item 1. holds, since the meet of any two distinct
elements of $T$ is $\bot_L$ (the meet of distinct
atoms is $\bot_L$ and the meet of an atom
and $\bot_L$ is $\bot_L$).
Item 3. holds because $T$ contains all the
join irreducibles of $\langle S\rangle$
and every element of $\langle S\rangle$
is a join of join irreducibles.
Item 2. holds because $S$ is a generating set
for the Boolean lattice $\langle S\rangle$
and each $t\in T$ is join irreducible.
That is, given $t\in T\;(\subseteq \langle S\rangle)$
it is possible to express $t$ as a word in $S$
written in disjunctive normnal form, but since
$t$ is join irreducible we do not need disjunction.
This means that $t$ is a meet of elements of $S$. \\\

There are cases not covered by the above
argument, namely those where $S$ does not contain
at least $2$ nonzero elements of $L$.
In these cases we have either
$|S|\leq 1$ or $S=\{\bot_L,s\}$
for some nonzero element $s\in L$. In any of these
cases we can take $T=S$ and have that 1., 2., 3. hold.

This makes sense, but now I'm confused about something else. Suppose that in my example picture, L is the lattice of intervals of natural numbers (and $+\infty$), with $\wedge$ set intersection and $[a, b) \vee [c, d) = [min(a, c), max(c, d))$. It seems to me that S and T in my picture do not generate Boolean algebras, but nonetheless satisfy my conditions. Is this because the lattice I've just defined is non-distributive?

Yes, $[1,2)\wedge([0,1)\vee [2,3))\neq ([1,2)\wedge [0,1))\vee ([1,2)\vee [2,3))$.
